# cannot install setup.py properly for face recognition

Tags: python, anaconda, face-recognition, dlib

i was trying to install face_recognition on spyder and i have to install cnmake and dlib first so while installing dlib i came across this error.

i tried following this site to install dlib but i got stuck

https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf

## this is what they show on command prompt

```
C:\Users\L30809\Desktop\dlib-master>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 129, in run
    cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
  File "setup.py", line 126, in get_cmake_version
    return re.search(r'version\s*([\d.]+)', out.decode()).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

## and this is what they show on spyder

```
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
  Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\L30809\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o0volf3j\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\L30809\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-spg4otqt\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\L30809\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o0volf3j\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\L30809\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o0volf3j\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "C:\Users\L30809\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o0volf3j\dlib\setup.py", line 126, in get_cmake_version
        return re.search(r'version\s*([\d.]+)', out.decode()).group(1)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

    ----------------------------------------
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  Failed building wheel for dlib
Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\L30809\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
```

Comment: have you installed [CMake](https://cmake.org/)?

Comment: What is the output of `cmake --version` on your computer?

Comment: @DrBwts yes i installed cmake by using pip install cmake

Comment: @DavisKing i tried typing cmake --version but nothing appeared on my command prompt so i manually went and check the version by looking at the path of the cmake and its 3.14.4

Comment: If running cmake in the terminal doesn’t work then cmake isn’t property installed. Install it from cmake.org.

Comment: Check python version and try switching between 2 and 3.

Comment: [Installation of Face_Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56732194)